# How to Convert Html To Xaml for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to convert HTML to XAML. I found a NuGet Package called [HtmlToXamlConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlToXamlConverter) but It seems it will not work with UWP apps. So How do I do it for UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the HtmlBlock control in the Windows App Studio Nuget package.  The HtmlBlock renders Html formatted content using a native Xaml representation.

https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs#html-block